# Execute Powershell command (get-user -Identity "John Doe" | FL) in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to execute `_Get-User -Identity "John Doe" | FL_` command within the following C# code.

```
       PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
       powershell.AddCommand("get-user");
       powershell.AddParameter("Identity", UserName.Text);
       try
       {
           runspace.Open();
           powershell.Runspace = runspace;
           Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

           var builder = new StringBuilder();
           foreach (var psObject in results)
           {
               builder.AppendLine(psObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
           }
           ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
       }
```

Where do I add the `_FL_` command?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be passing `results` to "FL" (a different Powershell command)? Or perhaps you can use the full command-string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have searched a lot. You can change regular powershell script instead of "WriteWhatYouWantToDo".

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke invo = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
invo.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

Command command = new Command("get-module -listAvailable | import-module\n" + WriteWhatYouWantToDo);

pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
try
{
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PSObject obj in results)
{
stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
}

string result1 = stringBuilder.ToString();
string result = result1.Substring(0, 250); //define global scope
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you add each command, it gets added to the pipeline. So if you want to do `format-list`, you can add that to the pipeline:

```
   powershell.AddCommand("get-user");
   powershell.AddParameter("Identity", UserName.Text);
   powershell.AddCommand("format-list");'
   //powershell.AddCommand("out-string");
```

But I am not sure what you want to do, as something like that can be done in C# using `results`

Comment: I think it is not going to work well but it is close. I would add to these commands one more: `powershell.AddCommand("Out-String");`. The cmdlet `format-list` does not return formatted text, it returns objects for formatting on actual output. We have to trigger this output.

Comment: @RomanKuzmin - Yeah, but that is why I question in the last line why you OP needs fl in the first place.